# Apache Cordova/Visual Studio 2015 tools fails to launch app in IOS simulator

Tags: ios, cordova, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-cordova, taco

I am trying to deploy a simple newly created `Cordova` app on `Mac` from `vs2015` it seems that the project is build successfully but I am getting the following error in visual studio and no app is installing or running on simulator.

> Starting launch process C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node.exe "C:\Users\RezaR\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\vs-tac\emulator.js"
>   --platform ios --action launch --path "c:\users\rezar\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\BlankCordovaApp2\BlankCordovaApp2\bld\ios\Debug\buildInfo.json"
>   --serverUrl http://RezaMac:3015/cordova --language en-US --loglevel warn  --cliVersion 5.4.1 --npmInstallDir "C:\Users\RezaR\AppData\Roaming\npm"  --deployTarget "iPhone 5S" Timed out connecting debugger to remote Apache Cordova app. See Output window for JavaScript console output.
>
> ------ Cordova tools 5.4.1 already installed. 
>   Requesting emulate on iOS Simulator for buildNumber 1462 on server http://RezaMac:3015/cordova... Failed to launch iOS remote for build c:\users\rezar\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\BlankCordovaApp2\BlankCordovaApp2\bld\ios\Debug\buildInfo.json to http://RezaMac:3015/cordova for deploy target iPhone 5S: Http 404: {"command":"build","vcordova":"5.4.1","cfg":"debug","loglevel":"warn","status":"Error","buildCommand":"build","buildPlatform":"ios","configuration":"debug","buildLang":"en-US","buildDir":"/Users/RezaRa/.taco_home/remote-builds/taco-remote/builds/1462","buildNumber":1462,"options":"","logLevel":0,"submissionTime":"2016-03-12T21:30:32.929Z","changeList":{"deletedFiles":[]},"buildSuccessful":true,"messageId":"EmulateFailedTimeout","messageArgs":[null],"message":"Error: timed out launching iOS simulator.","tgzFilePath":"/Users/RezaRa/.taco_home/remote-builds/taco-remote/builds/1462/upload_1462.tgz","appDir":"/Users/RezaRa/.taco_home/remote-builds/taco-remote/builds/1462/cordovaApp","statusTime":"2016-03-12T21:32:17.020Z","appName":"BlankCordovaApp2"}
>
> ------ Cordova tools 5.4.1 already installed. 
>   Requesting debug on remote iOS device for buildNumber 1462 on server http://RezaMac:3015/cordova... Failed to Debug iOS remote for build c:\users\rezar\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\BlankCordovaApp2\BlankCordovaApp2\bld\ios\Debug\buildInfo.json to http://RezaMac:3015/cordova : iPhone 5S

Then I tried below as mentioned in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35208495/tools-for-apache-cordova-visual-studio-2015-fails-to-launch-app-in-ios-simulator)

On the mac, go to `~/.taco_home/node_modules/taco-remote-lib/<VERSION>/node_modules/taco-remote-lib/` and run `npm uninstall ios-sim` && `npm install ios-sim@5.0.4`

but no chance

### My Environment:

On windows:

- Vs2015 Update 1
- Cordova 5.4.1

on Mac

- Yosemit
- Xcode 7.2.1
- Simulator 9.2
- Cordova 5.4.1
- Node 5.7.1

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I have found the problem and solution, in case of somebody else has the same problem:

- first run `remotebuild saveconfig` in `macos` `terminal`
- Open the `RemoteBuild.config` file in the `Text Editor` from the path of the previous step
- Change value of `appLaunchStepTimout` to 60000 (1 min)
- Change value of `emulatorLaunchTimeout` to 60000 (1 min)
- Save the file
- run `remotebuild` on terminal
- Run the project from `Visual studio` again