# 500 Error Debugging Apache Cordova app on iOS

Tags: ios, visual-studio-2015, taco

I am attempting to debug an **Apache Cordova app** from **Visual Studio 2015** on **iOS**.  The application builds just fine, and even launches in the simulator.  But I keep getting a `500 error` when `remotebuild` attempts the debug command, and I get the error `"Timed out connecting debugger to remote Apache Cordova app."`

Has anyone experienced a similar issue?

Comment: The output window shows the following:
`------ Cordova tools 6.0.0 already installed.
Requesting emulate on iOS Simulator for buildNumber 66095 on server http://192.168.31.80:3000/cordova...
Emulated - Successfully sent to ios Simulator`

Comment: `------ Cordova tools 6.0.0 already installed.
Requesting debug on remote iOS device for buildNumber 66095 on server http://192.168.31.80:3000/cordova...
Failed to Debug iOS remote for build xxx\buildInfo.json to http://192.168.31.80:3000/cordova :
iPhone 6`

Comment: Are you still having this issue? I work on the Tools for Apache Cordova team at Microsoft. Right now, we're investigating ways to make it easier for developers to recover from remote build errors in VS. It would be great to chat with you about this issue. Customer feedback is the number one way we make product design decisions, so I’d love it if you could make time for a 20min phone call this week or next to talk about how you understand and overcome build issues. jomatthi [at] Microsoft [dot] com

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like a timeout issue..

- first run remotebuild saveconfig in macos terminal
- Open the RemoteBuild.config file in the Text Editor from the path of the
  previous step
- Change value of appLaunchStepTimout to 60000 (1 min)
- Change value of emulatorLaunchTimeout to 60000 (1 min) Save the file
  run remotebuild on terminal
- Run the project from Visual studio again

I got these instructions from [Apache Cordova/Visual Studio 2015 tools fails to launch app in IOS simulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35963752/apache-cordova-visual-studio-2015-tools-fails-to-launch-app-in-ios-simulator).

Comment: That doesn't seem to make any difference.  I even increased it to 120000 (2 min).  The simulator launches the app and the splash screen in the app shows up, but when `remotebuild` attempts to connect the debugger.  I get an immediate `500 error` regardless of what I set the timeout to.  The app runs fine in the iPhone5 Ripple emulator.

Comment: The problem with remotebuild is that it takes a long time to load a large app, and so sometimes it just times out on the VS side as it waits on OSX. A way to speed up the process is to have the iOS simulator already open on your Mac. To emphasize, this is not a foolproof workaround, and you may need to do this a few times and just hope the process is fast enough.