# Why is Visual Studio TACO unable to find the app I am trying to debug?

Tags: ios, ionic-framework, visual-studio-cordova, taco

I am using visual studio running in parallels on a Mac.  The Mac functions as my build server for iOS.  I am trying to get debugging working from visual studio for both the simulator (iPad Air iOS 9.3) and an actual device (an actual iPad Air).  For now, it may be helpful to just focus on the simulator first.

When I try to launch to a simulator (iPad Air) from visual studio, or to an actual device my application launches on the device or simulator before visual studio appears to hang for a few moments, ultimately reporting the following error message:

> We were unable to find the app you're trying to debug.  Check that the >device is connected, awake, and unlocked.  Also, make sure it has Web >Inspector enabled.

The device is connected.  In the case of the simulator there is no device to connect.

The device is awake and unlocked.  In the case of the simulator there is nothing to awaken or unlock.  The application launches while visual studio is still debugging just before an error message is returned.

I have checked and double checked to see that web inspector is enabled on both the device and inside safari on the mac.  I am able to run the build from XCODE and debug through Safari.

It seems unusual that the application actually opens in the simulator before visual studio returns with the error that it is unable to find the app.  If visual studio is unable to find the app then why did it launch?

I will be most grateful for any assistance.

**Environment [Updated]**

I am using a MacBook Pro running Windows 10 in Parallels.

**Windows Configuration**

- Visual Studio 2015 Update 2
- Cordova 6.1.1
- TACO Updated 8.1
- Node 6.0.0

**MacBook Pro Configuration**

- Cordova 6.1.1
- Node 6.0.0
- iPad Mini 2 running iOS 9.2 (13C75)
- iPad Air 2 running 9.2.1 (13D15)

**Update 1:**  I have installed visual studio update 2 and still get the same error message.  I appreciate the suggestion though!

**Update 2:** Thank you for the suggestion.  I edited the config, changed the timeout settings and restarted the build server as suggested.  The error attaching to an actual device has changed into a warning with the same result.  The simulator maintains the same error.

Now the warning reads:

> Timed out launching the app.  Check your network connection to the mac and try >again.  If you are launching to a device, make sure you have Web Inspector >enabled on it.

I do have web inspector enabled.  It does not seem visual studio is waiting the full minute before coming back with an error or warning.  Furthermore, the visual studio environment appears to hang (not responding) while it is attempting to attach to the device or simulator.

I have tried on multiple networks as well and get the same results.

Is there any additional information I may provide that may be of assistance?

**Update 3:**

Any other suggestions, or additional information I may provide?  I am really stumped here.  Fortunately this is not a showstopper as I am able to do some debugging in safari when deployed to the device but it is frustrating.

Is it typical for visual studio to appear to hang when trying to attach to the device to debug?

I also do not believe visual studio is waiting the full duration of the timeout settings that have been configured.

I have updated every dependency I am able to think of and made sure the cordova versions match on ios and windows.  I am stumped here...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I increased the amount of memory available to the Windows 10 VM from 4GB to 5GB and the debugger is now attaching as expected without error.

I am posting this in the event it is helpful to someone else.

Answer (score 1):

What you're seeing may be the result of a timeout in the remotebuild tools, this can happen for a variety of reasons (including general network performance). Take a look at the following answer to another post ([Apache Cordova/Visual Studio 2015 tools fails to launch app in IOS simulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35963752/apache-cordova-visual-studio-2015-tools-fails-to-launch-app-in-ios-simulator/35964139#35964139)) for some guidance re: how to change the timeouts

> - first run `remotebuild saveconfig` in `macos` `terminal`
> - Open the `RemoteBuild.config` file in the `Text Editor` from the path of the previous step
> - Change value of `appLaunchStepTimout` to 60000 (1 min)
> - Change value of `emulatorLaunchTimeout` to 60000 (1 min)
> - Save the file
> - run `remotebuild` on terminal
> - Run the project from `Visual studio` again

Comment: Good suggestion.  I upped the timeout settings and the error changed to a warning but the result is the same.  As a side note it does not appear visual studio is waiting the full minute before throwing in the towel.  Thank you for your input.

Answer (score 0):

I have across the same error occasionally, but it has been happening a lot less with the latest VS 2015, Update 2 TACO Update 8.1 - If you can update to that level ([VS2015 Update 2](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/news/vs2015-update2-vs.aspx)), it may resolve the issue for you.

I still occasionally see this error with Update 2. But, it usually happens on a non-incremental (full) iOS build and appears to be timing related. Update 2 fixes many issues though, so I recommend that you upgrade.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion.  I attempted the solution above which seems like a reasonable approach for anyone who is stuck.  Unfortunately it did not resolve the issue for me.  I am now up to date, though, which is never a bad thing.  Thank you for the input.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit2:** The issue manifested itself one more time, so it wasn't a definitive fix, but it works fine for the most part now.

**Edit:** I have reset the iPad settings from Settings -> General -> Reset -> Reset all Settings and now it seems to work.

I have the exact same problem when testing on my iPad 1, but it works on my iPhone 6. They are both running iOS 9. I don't have any other iOS devices to test on, so I can't draw any exact conclusions from this.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem as you.
and I just tried to change from debug to release and everything is solved.
and i can do debugging to.
it is strange solution but on the error it says that it cannot just debug so that's why i thought about this.